# Easy Jet flight Amsterdam to Malaga with a change in London in the middle. Not allowed to board flight because of no UK entry Visa

Tags: uk, transit-visas, easyjet, residence-permits

I was flying from Amsterdam (Schipol Airport) to Malaga on Easy Jet and had to change planes in London. I am an Indian Citizen but have a Dutch Residence permit. I was not allowed to board the aircraft from Schipol to London by EasyJet because I do not have a UK entry visa. This was very surprising because I would only change flights in London, hence requiring only a transit visa and I am exempt from requiring a transit visa since I have a Dutch Residence permit see this [link to the UK visa requirements](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no). I was also allowed to pass through immigration in Schipol for this particular flight with just my passport and residence permit - I was not stopped by the immigration officer for not having a UK entry visa. However, the employees of EasyJet did not let me enter the flight when it was time for boarding.

Both my passport and residence permit were valid for more than 6 months at the time of the flight. What can I do about this situation?

Comment: "I was not stopped by the immigration officer for not having a UK entry visa": of course you weren't.  The Dutch officer's job is to make sure you haven't violated Schengen immigration law.  Dutch officers are not responsible for enforcing UK immigration law, nor are they trained to do so.

Comment: There are direct flights from Ansterdam to Malaga, why choose to route via the UK? Especially right now with all the travel chaos going on

Comment: This sounds like it is one of the "benefits" of Brexit.

Comment: @quarague Considering that the UK was never part of Schengen, not necessarily.

Comment: Uk is not in the EU anymore. This is Brexit.

Comment: @GACy20 What gerrit says.

Comment: Which London airport were you going to change at?

Comment: "London" is extremely vague. Which of its six airports do you mean? AFAIK EasyJet doesn't serve Heathrow, City or Southend (at least from Schiphol it doesn't) and there are very few flights to Stansted, so that leaves Gatwick or Luton. Airside transit on Gatwick might or might not be available between two (separate) EasyJet flights, and Luton doesn't have airside transit at all.

Comment: We don't have enough details to make an informed reply. it would be good to know the date of the flights and the flight numbers. There are many good reasons to deny boarding here. One of which is if the connection is shorter than MCT which is totally possible if the two flights were booked separately.

Comment: As far as I can tell, *none* of the London airports served by easyJet offer airside transit. That means your answer to the last question ("Will you pass through UK border control?") was wrong - you may not have any personal need to do so, but you'll be required to do so anyway as the airports simply don't provide facilities to transit without passing immigration. However, if we [change that answer to 'yes'](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes), it seems that your Dutch residence permit and onward booking still makes you eligible for visa-free transit.

Answer (score 14):

The main point is that Easyjet do not sell connecting flights. So what you actually bought was a flight from Amsterdam to London, and, separately, a flight from London to Malaga. You did **not** buy a flight from Amsterdam to Malaga with a connection in London (Easyjet just don’t sell that).

To let you board the flight from Amsterdam to London, Easyjet would have needed evidence that you would be allowed entry into the UK, without taking into account any further flights booked with them or anybody else. You definitively didn’t qualify for that. For them, that’s the end of the story.

Some airlines and/or agents will take into account further flights (with the same airline or with another airline). But they hardly have any obligation to do so, quite the contrary. Anything that would make anyone consider that the flights are somehow connecting could open the door to a whole new collection of problems for them (if you miss your connection, and they become liable for care, assistance and possibly compensation). So they have every reason to completely ignore any further flights, even if they’re booked on the same airline.

I’m afraid that in your situation, if you want to travel between Schengen airports, either travel only via other Schengen airports, or make sure all flights are on the same ticket/booking/PNR and you can transit airside and match the conditions for that.

Comment: *Anything that would make anyone consider that the flights are somehow connecting could open the door to a whole new collection of problems for them (if you miss your connection, and they become liable for care, assistance and possibly compensation).* This doesn't follow at all. easyJet are obliged to check that you have the documentation to enter the UK, which OP did. This doesn't create an obligation to assistance in the case of a missed connection.

Comment: @MJeffryes OP's documentation to enter the UK expired just a few hours after **scheduled** arrival so EasyJet would need to assist in case of a delay

Comment: @Anders Why? From what law?

Comment: @MJeffryes I'm just reading here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes (the onward ticket isn't valid for long and that flight can also be cancelled at any time)

Comment: @Anders But why would that put an obligation on easyJet. They need to check the passenger is eligible to enter the UK, which they are. If force majeure means the passenger misses this flight, that's not easyJet's problem. There is nothing in the TWOV rules that makes the airline responsible for the passenger leaving the UK within the 2 calendar day period, beyond checking they have a ticket and appropriate visa.

Comment: @MJeffryes so when the first flight gets delayed and the passenger gets to passport control in London too late and they now have no valid ticket to leave the UK, what do you think will happen? They will be refused entry, Easyjet will have to carry them back to Amsterdam and pay a substantial fine. So they clearly don’t want to be faced even with the prospect of the possibility of that happening, and they will refuse boarding.

Comment: Since we're all arguing hypotheticals, I looked at the guidance for airlines. From what I can gather if the passenger is denied entry the carrier will be required to remove them from the UK. But the obligation is only to check they have a ticket and relevant visa. In the event force majeure means they cannot depart in time, the most that the inbound airline would be responsible for is removing them from the UK, not for a fine. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1068088/Charging_procedures_-_a_guide_for_carriers.pdf

Answer (score 9):

There are two points here:

1. You selected "Airside Transit" in the link you gave, but you are flying with Easyjet, which means you would have two separate PNRs for the journey. That means the destination of your flight from Amsterdam is UK (not Malaga) and you should have authorization to enter UK. Even if you don't have checked in luggage and your actual intent is to make airside transit, that is not accepted by airlines unless you have a connecting flight (ticket till final destination on a single PNR). The visa required in such cases is "Visitor in Transit Visa" (not Direct Airside Transit), to be allowed boarding.
2. Even if you have to pass through border control, having a "common format residence permit from an EEA country or Switzerland" allows you to transit without a visa (TWV) but it is discretionary. Normally people are granted 48 hour leave to enter the UK to change planes or even airports. Therefore I have seen a lot of cases where airlines denied boarding even to holders of a non-UK visa which exempts a visitor in transit visa, but I have also seen cases where airlines allowed boarding to Indian citizens without any UK visa who even had to change airports in the UK and were granted temporary entry without a problem by border agents. But these cases were of those who were traveling to the US or Canada on a single PNR but had a change of airport (Heathrow to Gatwick).

The discretionary nature of the provision provides a lot of leverage to the airlines to make boarding judgements. Going to North America from India on a single PNR ticket and going from mainland Europe to mainland Europe, thus effectively taking a detour, via UK on two separate tickets are two very different cases.

But I have never personally known an airline allowing boarding to the UK (to Indian citizens) with different PNR tickets. You may try to contact EasyJet quoting the UKVI website (please also show them the page where you are even allowed to travel where you need to pass through passport control). But as the decision rests with the airline, and the language on the UKVI website makes the provision sound very discretionary so you may not a positive response from them.

Comment: Why is this "discretionary" ? https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes clearly states that there is an exemption for holders of an EEA residence permit. Can the airlines unilaterally decide to make their own Visa requirements?

Comment: First, it says "You may be eligible to transit without a visa if:", notice "may be able to" instead of "can". Then it says "You will not be able to transit without a visa if a Border Force officer decides you do not qualify under the immigration rules. You can apply for a transit visa before you travel if you’re unsure whether you qualify for transiting without a visa.". It is totally at the discretion of the border agents.

Comment: Agreed, but it shouldn't be the airlines discretion. Are you saying that all exemptions listed for Direct Airside Transit and Visitor in Transit Visa are meaningless? Then why list them in the first place ?

Comment: No, the language used for DATV is "You do not need a visa if you have one of the following:", which different from visa without transit. Also, airlines denying boarding to cirizens of developing countries is pretty common even for visa cree countries. Indian citizens are routinely separated from boarding queues in UAE airports and denied boarding for flights to Serbia despite Serbia being visa free for Indians. Same happens at Indian airports, every single day.

Comment: Thomas Cruise, that's true, a mismatch between the perception of western citizens and what actual rules are, how they are implemented at the ground level. I've noticed that a lot on this website. Most westerners have powerful passports and seldom experience these things but these are routine for us and require careful reading of rules and other people's experiences before booking tickets.

Comment: @ThomasCruise This equally applies to a non visa national seeking entry as a visitor to the UK. And for someone who holds a visa for that matter. It's always at the discretion of the border officer. So by this argument, easyJet can deny boarding to literally anyone who requires permission to enter the UK.

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment, that happens a lot (but for visa free countries). But having a visa from US/CANADA/UK/Japan is almost a guarantee that you will not be denied boarding for visa-free places. A lot of times hostile airline and immigration officers of many countries suddenly change tune and demeanour the moment they see a visa from US/UK/Canada/Japan. This is the ground reality.

Answer (score 4):

You may have fallen between the cracks here.

You have booked two seperate tickets and hence you would need a "Visitor in Transit" visa and not the "Direct Airside Visa" you have linked. In either case though, you should be exempted as a holder of an EEA residence permit. See https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes

However, most airlines use IATA to check entry requirements and if you poke in your data (as single flight from AMS to the UK), you would indeed need a Visa to enter into the UK. See https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

It depends here how the agent entered your information into the IATA search system. If they would have entered it as a single trip with a layover in the UK and a dutch residence permit you would be fine without a Visa.

Since Easy Jet is "point to point" airlines which doesn't allow booking connecting flights, the agents probably entered this as a single AMS->LON trip.
This makes sense since the UK concept if "Visitor in Transit Visa" is fairly unique, for almost all other countries there is no difference between "connecting on separate tickets" and "entry into the country". IATA has no concept of "transiting on separate tickets"

> What can I do about this situation?

Read up on Easy Jet's terms and conditions. Look for "denied boarding" and check what the rules and potential compensations are. Contact Easy Jet with documentation that your status was "Visitor in Transit" since you had an onward ticket in less than 48 hours and that you were exempted from a Visa requirement because of your EAA residence permit.

Comment: From EasyJet's perspective, the first link says "have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive". Since the first flight might be delayed OP might not have an onward flight.

Comment: Sure, buy by that reasoning no one would be ever able to qualify for "Visitor in Transit" and the whole category would be pointless. That's possible but hard to imagine

Comment: Wouldn't "visitor in transit" still be useful for a single ticket with an airport change or a hotel stay land-side?

Comment: How is that different? Your second flight can be delayed or cancelled either way or the passenger can simply decide not to go back to the airport

Comment: On a single ticket the airline the will transport the passenger to the final destination without additional cost.